# Delete Load Tests from VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, load-testing

How can I delete unused load tests from VSTS? I really can't find any delete button.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t delete the load test now. There is the user voice that you can vote and follow up:

[Add possibility to delete a Load Test from VSTS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17738881-add-possibility-to-delete-a-load-test-from-vsts)